# TreeMap with two keys

Tags: java, hashmap, multiple-columns, treemap

I am making a simple 2D java sidescroller, and right now, I have a `HashMap` where I have a class `Location` as the key, and `Entity` as the value. I want to be able to store the `Entity` objects in a `TreeMap` (or something similar) where I will have 2 keys: `double x` and `double y`. and be able to get all values, where first key is between specific numbers, and the second key too. So far I only found `TreeMap`, but it only allows me to have 1 double as the key. Is there a way in Java to implement that without having to loop through every key, (suck as `Location`) and checking if the 2 numbers in it are within the specified bounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's not pretty - one way to do this is with a `TreeMap<Double, TreeMap<Double, Entity>>`. Then to get all entities within a square, you can do `map.subMap(minX, maxX).subMap(minY, maxY).values();`

Answer (score 2):

I would use 2 TreeMaps, one for x and one for y:

```
    NavigableMap<Double, Object> x = new TreeMap<>();
    NavigableMap<Double, Object> y = new TreeMap<>();

    Object obj1 = new Object();
    x.put(2.0, obj1);
    y.put(10.0, obj1);

    // find objects with x between 1 and 3; y between 9 and 11 

    Collection<Object> c1 = x.subMap(1.0, true, 3.0, true).values();
    Collection<Object> c2 = y.subMap(9.0, true, 11.0, true).values();
    c1.retainAll(c2);
```

now c1 contains result